# check the element value in xml file

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xpath

this is my xml:-

```
<results>
    <result>
        <Country_Code>IN</Country_Code>
        <Country_Name>India</Country_Name>
        <Region_Name>Gujarat</Region_Name>
        <City>Rajkot</City> 
        <lat>13.060422</lat>
        <lng>80.24958300000003</lng>
    </result>
    <result>
        <Country_Code>KE</Country_Code>
        <Country_Name>Kenya</Country_Name>
        <Region_Name>Vihiga</Region_Name>
        <City>Kakamega</City> 
        <lat>0.1182473</lat>
        <lng>34.7334515999997</lng>
    </result>
</results>
```

this is script:-

```
<script>
    var xml;
    $.get(
        "sea.xml",
        null,
        function (data) {
            xml = data;
        },
        "xml"
    );
    function get_list(ls) {
        var elName = $('#select').val();
        var value = $('#value').val();
        var xPath = '//lat[@value '+ ls +' "'+elName+'"]'and  var xPathh='//lng[@value '+ ls +' '+value+']'+'/../City/@value';
        var xPath = '//[lat = ('+ elName+') and lng = ('+ value +')]'+'/result';

        var iterator = xml.evaluate(xPath, xml.documentElement, null,
            XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
        var thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();
        var str = '';
        while (thisNode) {
            if (str) {
                str += ', ';
            }
            str += thisNode.textContent;
            thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();
        }

        $("#result").text(str);
    }
</script>
```

this is html code:-

```
<body>
    <input type="text" id="select">
    <input type="text" id="value">
    <input type="button" name="button" value="Search" onclick="get_list('=')">
    <div id="result">
    </div>
</body>
```

i have two textbox:-

in first textbox enter latitude value `13.060422` (its on my xml file)

in second textbox enter longitude value `80.24958300000003`(its on my xml file)

then both are match in my xml element value return all sibling value like

`IN India Gujarat Rajkot 13.060422 80.24958300000003`

thanks

Comment: Hi Jack, can you formulate a question? It's not clear what you need to know.

Comment: and double-check your XML, there is an parser error — "error on line 5 at column 44: Opening and ending tag mismatch: Region_Name line 0 and Region".

Comment: @dome thanks for inform me about xml error here i am edit my question please check now.

Comment: @jacklanza, do you need that using jquery?

Comment: @PragneshChauhan i just now solve this query but a little bit requirement wait i edit my question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you using jquery try this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/EApyj/3/)**

```
var xml = "<results><result><Country_Code>IN</Country_Code><Country_Name>India</Country_Name><Region_Name>Gujarat</Region_Name><City>Rajkot</City><lat>13.060422</lat><lng>80.24958300000003</lng></result><result><Country_Code>KE</Country_Code><Country_Name>Kenya</Country_Name><Region_Name>Vihiga</Region_Name><City>Kakamega</City><lat>0.1182473</lat><lng>34.7334515999997</lng></result></results>";


xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml );
$xml = $( xmlDoc );
function get_list(ls){
   $lat = $("#select").val();
   $lng = $("#value").val();
   $title = $xml.find( "lat:contains('"+$lat+"')" ).closest('result');    
   $t = $title.find("lng:contains('"+$lng+"')").closest('result');    
   $str = $t.contents().map(function(){
       return $(this).contents().eq(0).text();
   }).get().join(' ');

   $("#result").text($str);
}
```

Comment: can you help me some how to set this output as a table format?